# arduino - obtain data from rabbitmq

Tags: arduino, rabbitmq, mqtt

Im not a English so sorry for my language at first.

**!Problem resolved: look to comments section!**

Current state: I developed small android app to send data for my own rabbitmq server. Next, I installed mqtt plugin.

Problem: how to connect rabbitmq with arduino ?
I tried to connect by given piece of code, without results

```
void connectMQTT() {
  Serial.print("Attempting to MQTT broker: ");
  Serial.print("127.0.0.1);
  mqttClient.setUsernamePassword(MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWD);

  while (!mqttClient.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883)) {
    delay(5000);
  }

  Serial.println("You're connected to the MQTT broker");
  mqttClient.subscribe("NanoIot33_1/sub");
}
```

Bellow is config for mqttClient

```
  #include <WiFiNINA.h>
  #include <ArduinoMqttClient.h>

  WiFiClient    wifiClient;
  MqttClient    mqttClient(wifiClient);
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` ALWAYS points to the device/host the code is running on, you are NOT running an MQTT broker on your arduino device...

Comment: As mentioned above, you should use the address of some online demo MQTT broker, or setup a broker by yourself and connect to it, by using it's address instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: yes, i changed 127.0.0.1 to ip from my pc (got from ipconfig). Still no luck. i verifed that i can ping pc ip address from arduino, but nothing else.
@FilipKubicz i installed mqtt plugin for rabbitmq so i have broker (or at least I think so).

Comment: Ok, I was soooooo dump. My mqtt server is running on virtualbox. I opened a good port from virtualbox, but to 127.0.0.1 instead of ip from ipconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mqtt server is running on virtualbox. I opened a good port from virtualbox, but to 127.0.0.1 instead of ip from ipconfig.